# Add a field if match

Tags: match, logstash, logstash-grok

i'm triyng to monitor an irc server. And i'm loot for a way to create a new numeral field (example: Alert_level) only if a message match a specific word inside. 
Example: Message: ABC | Alert_level: 1 ; Message: ZYX | Alert_level: 3.

Its the running code

```
input {
        irc {
                channels => "#xyz"
                host => "a.b.c"
                nick => "myusername"
                catch_all => true
          get_stats => true
        }
}


output {
        stdout { codec => "rubydebug" }
        elasticsearch {
                                        hosts => "localhost"
                                        index => "logstash-irc-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: it not work http://pastebin.com/tvfzCRKA

Comment: You'll need a `grok` filter. Show us a sample message you're getting from the `irc` input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Val suggested above you might need to use the [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok) filter in order match something from the `input`. For example your `filter` could look something like this:

```
filter {        
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:somedata}" }          
    }

    if "ZYX" in [message]{ <-- change your condition accordingly
        mutate {
            add_field => { "%{Alert_level}" => "12345" } <-- somefield is the field name
            convert => { "Alert_level" => "integer" }    <-- do the conversion
        }

    }   
}
```

**NOTE** that you have to do the conversion in order to create a numeric field through `logstash`, where you can't directly create one. The above is just a sample so that you can reproduce. Do change the `grok` match in respect to your requirement. Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you!. i used this and work: if "github" in [message] {mutate {add_field => { "Alert_level" => "1" }}}